# Why isn't my progress bar showing anything?

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I have a custom progress bar and basically when I enter a value and then press a button, I would like to have that progress bar update. My progress bar is going to have only three values basically it can be 0 percent, 33 percent, 66 percent, or 100 percent. For some reason when I do go to the page with the progress bar and even enter the value into the TextView and then enter the button, it's just showing a loading circle for some reason that never ends. I've posted my all the code needed for the progress bar, so does anyone know why it's not showing the correct progress bar and why it's just showing that loading circle?

**custom_progressBar.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Define the background properties like color etc -->
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#000001"
            android:centerColor="#0b131e"
            android:centerY="1.0"
            android:endColor="#0d1522"
            android:angle="270"
            />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Define the progress properties like start color, end color etc -->
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#007A00"
                android:centerColor="#007A00"
                android:centerY="1.0"
                android:endColor="#06101d"
                android:angle="270"
                />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

**progressBarShirts.java**

```
package ankitkaushal.app.healthysizing;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.sax.TextElementListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class progressBarShirts extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_progress_bar_shirts);

        final DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        final TextView currentSizeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentSizeShirts);
        Button enterNewSizeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newSizeEnterButtonShirts);
        final EditText newSize = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newSizeShirts);
        final String currentSize = db.getCurrentShirtSize();
        currentSizeDisplay.setText("Your current size: " + currentSize);
        Drawable draw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progressbar);

        enterNewSizeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String size = newSize.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
                currentSizeDisplay.setText("Your current size: " + size);
                db.updateSizeShirts(size);
            }

        });

        ProgressBar shirts = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarShirts);
        shirts.setProgressDrawable(draw);
        String startSize = db.getStartSizeShirts();
        String newCurrentSize = db.getCurrentShirtSize();
        String limit = db.getLimit("setLimitShirts");
        shirts.setMax(100);

        if (startSize.equals("XL") && limit.equals("S")) {

            if (newCurrentSize.equals("L")) {
                // Fill progress bar by 1/3

                shirts.setProgress(33);
            }

            if (newCurrentSize.equals("M")) {
                // Fill progress bar by 2/3

                shirts.setProgress(66);
            }

            if (newCurrentSize.equals("S")) {
                // Fill progress bar 100 percent

                shirts.setProgress(100);

                // Give a toast saying you've reached your limit
                Toast.makeText(this, "You've reached your limit! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // Set all values in database to null
                db.removeLImit("setLimitShirts");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_progress_bar_shirts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#29A9D2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Track your progress"
        android:id="@+id/TrackProgressShirts"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Current Size: Large"
        android:id="@+id/currentSizeShirts"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/newSizeShirts"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="Enter your new size"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter new size"
        android:id="@+id/newSizeEnterButtonShirts"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progressbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBarShirts"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:minWidth="300dp"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:maxWidth="300dp"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:indeterminateOnly="true"
        android:progress="0" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is progress always shows zero progress?

Comment: Yeah I think so because when go to that page, it's just showing a loading circle and then when I enter in the value and then click the button, it still shows a loading circle, a progress bar never appears.